# Is there a way to find saved items when using SaveOrUpdate method in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, isession

Is there a way to find saved items when using SaveOrUpdate method in hibernate. Basically, I need to know if an item is just updated or it is actualy inserted within one session.

Thansk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at NHibernate interceptors.

[Implementing NHibernate Interceptors](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/15/implementing-nhibernate-interceptors/)

[Interceptors](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-11-interceptors-and/1nr4enxv3dpeq/14#)

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving objects, as usual transient objects doesn't has an Id, and you can create a list with all processing objects which has an Id. Then you can iterate objects and find objects with new Id - they've been "saved".